# Why can't the import be resolved?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've seen several answers to this question, albeit none of the solutions have worked for my particular situation. I'm trying to get started building an API with Flask. When I try to import Flask-RESTful, I get an error in VS Code. For context, I am using Windows 11. Here are the first two lines of my .py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
```

The error I get reads as:

```
Import "flask_restful" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)
```

Now, to add more context, I've checked to make sure the interpreter path is set using `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the Command Palette and selecting the correct (and the only) Python interpreter for the project inside my virtual environment. When I run `pip list`, I get this output:

```
(api) C:\Users\<Username>\OneDrive\Documents\PythonProjects\api>pip list
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------
aiohttp                 3.8.1
aiosignal               1.2.0
alembic                 1.8.0
aniso8601               9.0.1
anyio                   3.6.1
async-timeout           4.0.2
attrs                   21.4.0
bleach                  5.0.1
certifi                 2022.6.15
charset-normalizer      2.1.0
click                   8.1.3
click-log               0.4.0
colorama                0.4.5
deprecation             2.1.0
docutils                0.19
dotty-dict              1.3.0
Flask                   2.1.2
Flask-Migrate           3.1.0
Flask-RESTful           0.3.9
Flask-SQLAlchemy        2.5.1
flask-swagger           0.2.14
frozenlist              1.3.0
gitdb                   4.0.9
GitPython               3.1.27
gotrue                  0.5.0
greenlet                1.1.2
h11                     0.12.0
httpcore                0.14.7
httpx                   0.21.3
idna                    3.3
importlib-metadata      4.12.0
invoke                  1.7.1
itsdangerous            2.1.2
Jinja2                  3.1.2
keyring                 23.6.0
Mako                    1.2.1
MarkupSafe              2.1.1
multidict               6.0.2
packaging               21.3
pip                     22.0.4
pkginfo                 1.8.3
postgrest-py            0.10.2
psycopg2                2.9.3
pydantic                1.9.1
Pygments                2.12.0
pyparsing               3.0.9
python-dateutil         2.8.2
python-gitlab           3.6.0
python-semantic-release 7.28.1
pytz                    2022.1
pywin32-ctypes          0.2.0
PyYAML                  6.0
readme-renderer         35.0
realtime                0.0.4
requests                2.28.1
requests-toolbelt       0.9.1
rfc3986                 1.5.0
semver                  2.13.0
setuptools              58.1.0
setuptools-scm          7.0.4
six                     1.16.0
smmap                   5.0.0
sniffio                 1.2.0
SQLAlchemy              1.4.39
storage3                0.3.4
supabase                0.5.8
supabase-client         0.2.4
tomli                   2.0.1
tomlkit                 0.10.2
tqdm                    4.64.0
twine                   3.8.0
typing_extensions       4.3.0
urllib3                 1.26.10
webencodings            0.5.1
websockets              9.1
Werkzeug                2.1.2
wheel                   0.37.1
yarl                    1.7.2
zipp                    3.8.0
```

Why would the `flask...Flask` import work, but not `flask_restful`? I can see both in the [Lib\site-packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PF8u.png) folder in my project directory and the output from `pip list` *outside* the virtual environment is different, which signals to me that there isn't an issue with the path or directories.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that when I run the code using `Ctrl + Alt + N`, I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<Username>\OneDrive\Documents\PythonProjects\api\api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'
```

Again, no errors with importing flask, only with flask_restful.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time. I'm happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks.

EDIT: I have updated pip and attempted to simply run the program inside the command prompt. [This is what I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byyiP.png) I'm still getting the import error inside VS Code, though. I am going to see if using a different version of Python makes a difference. Thanks everyone for all of your help so far, I appreciate it!

EDIT: Okay, it seems like the issue is a little closer to being solved. So, I updated pip. I retried setting the interpreter path and, which some of you mentioned, it turns out that I'd been doing it wrong. I had to do `Ctrl + Shift + P >> Python: Select Interpreter >> Enter interpreter path` and select the correct path that way. I did this by going into the project directory, going to the scripts folder, and selecting `python.exe`.

That solved the issue with Pylance. I no longer see an error in the editor when working on the project. However, the interpreter will not show in the bottom right hand corner of the window. That may just be a bug and I can either look through the issues on GitHub or open a new one some other time I assume.

When I run the code with `Ctrl + Alt + N` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` relating to flask_restful again. But, when I run `set flask_app=api.py >> flask run` in the terminal, it has changed from a white background in the browser to a black background and displays the message it is intended to display (a simple "Hello, World" as a test).

Should I just keep going until I run into another issue? I also tried `python -m api` and that worked as well. Should I just ignore the VS Code output window? Also, sorry about the late replies. I appreciate everyone's help and patience.

Comment: While it likely isn't the issue here, can you try updating your pip to the latest version (currently 22.1.2) just so we can definitely rule that out?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Despite you saying otherwise this very much sounds like it is *not* using your virtual environment. Not sure, perhaps it is possible to use the interpreter binary from there but still not activating the venv. Can you run the script from a terminal outside of vscode where you manually activate the venv first?

Comment: @AaronMeese I updated and got a little bit of a different output, but I'm still getting the same errors inside VS Code. I'm going to update the post now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @sr0812 I am using version 3.10.5. I am going to try using 3.7 (the most recent version that Flask mentions in their documentation) and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: @lucidbrot I tried this while updating pip as suggested by AaronMeese and will update the post now to show what happens. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything useful in your newly added screenshot (btw, if you paste the text instead it will be easier to read and to find by google) ... is there no output at all when you run it this way? Does that mean it is running correctly from the terminal?

Comment: @lucidbrot That's my question! I'm not sure but hopefully this latest update (not yet added) will be the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Ctrl+Shift+P` command, search for and `select Python:Select Interpreter`(Or click directly on the python version displayed in the lower right corner), and select the correct interpreter.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have tried this! I will try again and see if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @dorraj. After reading your updated content, when you select the correct interpreter, do you reinstall the python package?

Comment: Unless I keep the virtual environment inside project folder, my third party imports don't get recognised. Django imports work fine.

Answer (score 1):

ok
this issue is definitely with the chose python interpreter.

1. check what is the version of python you are using
2. check whether you are using wsl on windows or linux or command prompt

now in my case choose the interpreter was not solving the issue. I even tried the virtual environment and giving a path. but python by default was installing the .exe in a hidden folder and i couldn't find the files in the env folder

i was using wsl on windows and visual studio code.

so i ran pip installed outside the env. and also on the powershell/cmd  and the terminal. and the error went away.